# how to convert xts index or time to year

Tags: r, xts, posixct

For annual data (such as Annual Income Statements), I would like to keep xts format but I need to convert the index of the table to "only year". There are yearmon and yearqtr classes but I did not find "year" only class to work with xts.

```
# IS is annual reports of incomes. time(IS) is POSIXct.
library(quantmod)
IS <- viewFin(get(getFin("IBM")), "IS", "A") # Download data
IS <- as.xts(t(IS)) # Convert to xts
time(IS) <- as.yearqtr(time(IS))  ## works to have quarterly index
time(IS) <- as.yearmon(time(IS))  ## works to have monthly index
time(IS) <- ????(time(IS))  ## To have yearly index with xts class
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example?  Perhaps ``format(IS, "%Y")`

Comment: I edited the question to have reproducible example. Your solution does not work since xts does not accept character or numeric class for index. 
> time(IS) <- format(time(IS), "%Y")
Error in `time<-.xts`(`*tmp*`, value = c("2012", "2013", "2014", "2015" : 
  unsupported ‘index’ index type of class ‘character’

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you explained why you need to have the index as "year" only. Xts has an indexFormat command that allows you to control how dates are displayed, and while I've never used it I assume it will allow you to display only the year of any given index entry.

A more extreme solution would be to convert every date to the first of the year in that year. Here's some code to help do this:

```
first.of.year <- function(x)           # Given a date, returns the first day of that year
     return(as.Date(paste(year(as.Date(x)),"-01-01", sep="")))

index(x) <- first.of.year(index(x))
```